# Why are the contents of my JSP file overwriting my JavaScript and CSS files?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jsp

I am making the front-end side of a Java application for a class project, and one of my JSP files links to JavaScript files, as well as a CSS file. However, when I try to run my project on the server and display it in browser, I get the following errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/othello-pm/resources/scripts/game-screen.js".
game:8 

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/othello-pm/resources/styling/game-screen.css".
blah:1

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/othello-pm/resources/scripts/game-screen.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

When I look into the file contents of my JS and CSS files, it appears that their content has been replaced with the content of the HTML file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPUo4.png (I apologize for not showing the image directly, this is my first question, so I don't have permission to add it).

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

## UPDATE #1 (05/23/15)

---

This is my current `web.xml`. It hasn't really been changed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>othello-pm</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

## UPDATE #2 (05/25/15)

---

I managed to get it working.
There were a lot of little things that went into it, so I'm not sure what exactly was the tipping point of working vs. non-working, but here are the changes I made, for those reading in the future:

- Added meta tag to the head of the .jsp file
- Changed src paths of JS/CSS links to be relative to the server, rather than the file directories
- Made sure that all wild-card url paths of the servlets were kept to a minimum, and that they only were called with a specific keyword ("index/*" vs "/*", which is probably one of the biggest problems that was in the project)

Thanks to all those who helped out.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in your web.xml and all requests are being served by the same jsp? Post more details about your app on the server side (file layout, web.xml, etc)

Comment: It's caused by a new browser security feature that blocks files with the wrong mime type. Try a different browser and see if you get a different result.  It's a good question ... I'll try to post some more details for you.

Comment: @Robert I ran this in IE and FireFox, and both have the same errors.

Comment: @JPMoresmau http://i.imgur.com/JpDlS1O.png is an image showing my file structure in text format. I tried to do it with my previous comment, but I couldn't figure out how to add line breaks for the formatting.

Comment: can you please add the content of your web.xml in the original post? may be there is a global mime mapping to html or something similar...

Comment: That can happen if you mistakenly mapped a servlet on an URL pattern of `/` which forwards to that JSP.

Comment: You have probably did changes to the jsp, and it still unable to interpret static resource.